# How to deal with long initialization of an Akka child actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have an actor which creates a child actor to perform some lengthy computations.

The problem is that the initialization of the child actor takes a few seconds and all messages that the parent actor sends to the child between it is created and gets fully initialized are dropped.

This is the logic of the code that I am using:

```
class ChildActor extends Actor {
  val tagger = IntializeTagger(...) // this takes a few seconds to complete

  def receive = {
    case Tag(text) => sender ! tagger.tag(text)
    case "hello" => println("Hello")
    case _ => println("Unknown message")
  }
}

class ParentActor extends Actor {
  val child = context.ActorOf(Props[ChildActor], name = "childactor")

  // the below two messages seem to get lost
  child ! "hello"
  child ! Tag("This is my sample text")

  def receive = {
     ...
  }
}
```

How could I get around that problem? Is it possible to make the parent actor wait until the child is fully initialized? I will be using the child actor with routing and possibly on remote actor systems.

**EDIT**

Following drexin's advice I have change my code into:

```
class ChildActor extends Actor {
  var tagger: Tagger = _

  override def preStart() = {
    tagger = IntializeTagger(...) // this takes a few seconds to complete
  }

  def receive = {
    case Tag(text) => sender ! tagger.tag(text)
    case "hello" => println("Hello")
    case _ => println("Unknown message")
  }
}

class ParentActor extends Actor {
  var child: ActorRef = _

  override def preStart() = {
    child = context.ActorOf(Props[ChildActor], name = "childactor")

    // When I add
    // Thread.sleep(5000)
    // here messages are processed without problems

    // wihout hardcoding the 5 seconds waiting 
    // the below two messages seem to get lost
    child ! "hello"
    child ! Tag("This is my sample text")
  }

  def receive = {
     ...
  }
}
```

but the problem remains. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of akka are you using. I'm having difficulty simulating your issue. Everything seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @cmbaxter: I am using akka 2.2-M2.

Comment: This question and its answers jointly form one of the most confusing question and answers set I've yet seen on Akka actors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't initialize the `tagger` in the constructor, but in the `preStart` hook, this way the messages will be collected in the message box and delivered, when the actor is ready.

**edit**:

You should do the same for the actor creation in your `ParentActor` class, because you would have the same problem, if the `ChildActor` would respond, before the `ParentActor` is initialized.

**edit2**:

I created a simple example, but I was not able to reproduce your problems. Following code works perfectly fine:

```
import akka.actor._

case class Tag(x: String)

class ChildActor extends Actor {
  type Tagger = String => String
  var tagger: Tagger = _

  override def preStart() = {
    tagger = (x: String) => x+"@tagged" // this takes a few seconds to complete
    Thread.sleep(2000) // simulate time taken to initialize Tagger
  }

  def receive = {
    case Tag(text) => sender ! tagger(text)
    case "hello" => println("Hello")
    case _ => println("Unknown message")
  }
}

class ParentActor extends Actor {
  var child: ActorRef = _

  override def preStart() = {
    child = context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor], name = "childactor")

    // When I add
    // Thread.sleep(5000)
    // here messages are processed without problems

    // wihout hardcoding the 5 seconds waiting 
    // the below two messages seem to get lost
    child ! "hello"
    child ! Tag("This is my sample text")
  }

  def receive = {
    case x => println(x)
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")

  system.actorOf(Props[ParentActor])
}
```

Output is:

```
[info] Running Main
Hello
This is my sample text@tagged
```

Comment: I am afraid that this does not solve my problem. I updated the post to explain it further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thanks to it I realized what my problem was: I was doing system.shutdown() in my main application before actors had a chance to respond! It was stupid but took me a long time to figure out. Thank you for your effort, I am marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes, it should work fine with initialization in constructor or preStart. There is a configurable creation-timeout (default 20 s).

Comment: On a side note, shouldn't all long-running operations be wrapped in `blocking { ... }`?

Comment: in my case, I was sending an ask request to my actor from a plain scala `Object` singleton (not a parent actor), and for some reason the child actor wouldn't respond after it finished initializing in the `prestart`. [@cmbaxter stash/become/unstash solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17065069/1080804) worked for me though.

Comment: Messages are queued until the actor is initialized. Without seeing the code it's very hard to say why it didn't work in your case.

Answer (score 10):

I think what you might be looking for is the combo of `Stash` and `become`.  The idea will be that the child actor will set it's initial state to uninitialized, and while in this state, it will stash all incoming messages until it is fully initialized.  When it's fully initialized, you can unstash all of the messages before swapping behavior over to the initialized state.  A simple example is as follows:

```
class ChildActor2 extends Actor with Stash{
  import context._
  var dep:SlowDependency = _

  override def preStart = {
    val me = context.self
    Future{
      dep = new SlowDependency
      me ! "done"
    }
  }

  def uninitialized:Receive = {
    case "done" => 
      unstashAll
      become(initialized) 
    case other => stash()
  }

  def initialized:Receive = {
    case "a" => println("received the 'a' message")
    case "b" => println("received the 'b' message")   
  }

  def receive = uninitialized
}
```

Notice in the `preStart` that I'm doing my initialization asynchronously, so as to not halt the startup of the actor.  Now this is a bit ugly, with closing over the mutable `dep` var.  You could certainly handle it by instead sending a message to another actor that handles instantiation of the slow dependency and sends it back to this actor.  Upon receiving the dependency, it will then call `become` for the `initialized` state.

Now there is one caveat with `Stash` and I'll paste it in right from the Akka docs:

```
Please note that the Stash can only be used together with actors that 
have a deque-based mailbox. For this, configure the mailbox-type of the 
dispatcher to be a deque-based mailbox, such as 
akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox (see Dispatchers (Scala)).
```

Now if this does not suite you, you can try a more `DI` type approach and let the slow dependency be injected into the child actor via it's constructor.  So you would define the child actor like so:

```
class ChildActor(dep:SlowDependency) extends Actor{
    ...
}
```

Then when starting up this actor, you would do it as follows:

```
context.actorOf(new Props().withCreator(new ChildActor(slowDep)), name = "child-actor")
```

Comment: First, you should never close over mutable state and second, you should never close over the `ActorContext`. Calling become/unbecome from outside of the actors context can lead to serious problems.

Comment: @drexin, thanks for the heads up.  I modified my answer a little.  I know it's ugly closing over `dep`, but it's mitigated by the fact that nothing should be using `dep` until it transitions into the `initialized` state

Comment: Still, I would not recommend doing that. My proposed solution works and preStart is already called asynchronously. The `preStart` hook is meant to be used for initialization code. There is no need to wrap it in another future.

Comment: @cmbaxter: thank you for your effort. It was my stupid mistake of calling system.shutdown() prematurely.

Comment: @drexin You closed over mutable state in your own answer, e.g. `tagger` in `ChildActor`. Could you elaborate a bit about why this is ok?

Comment: Where exactly did I close over mutable state here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to send a "ready" message from the child actor to the parent and start sending messages to the child actor only after this message will be received. You can do it just in `receive()` method for simple use cases or you can use `become` or `FSM` to change parent actor behavior after the child will be initialized (for example, store the messages for the child in some intermediate storage and send them all when it will be ready).

Comment: I understand your point but what if the actor which is now a child was launched not from within another actor but just from the main thread? There must be an easier way to deal with the situation, don't you think?

Comment: Then the messages could be stashed in the "child" actor (as cmbaxter suggested).